# What happens when a tag-synonym is cancelled?

Tags: support, tag-management

Recently there was a discussion about removing previously created synonym of some tags, so that the two tags are separate again. (And we could probably find several related discussion in the past.)

My first question is how is this done. Is it something moderators can can do? Or is some action from SE staff needed?

Another question is what happens when the synonym is removed. We have many questions tagged (master-tag). Some of them might have been tagged by (slave-tag) at the time when the synonym was created. Some of them might be tagged (master-tag), but they got this tag after a user explicitly typed (slave-tag) when entering the tags.<sup>1</sup> After removing the synonym, do all question keep the (master-tag)? Or do some of the questions get the (slave-tag)? (For example, the two types of questions mentioned before seem like a reasonable candidates.)

Last question: Does it make a difference whether the two tags have been merged<sup>2</sup> or only synonymized?

---

<sup>1</sup>Number of such posts is [shown in the list of tag-synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190477/what-does-renames-mean-in-the-list-of-tag-synonyms).

<sup>2</sup>See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11162/what-is-the-difference-between-merging-two-tags-and-synonymizing-two-tags) for explanation of the difference between these two options. Based on the answer to the following post, it seem that there might be a difference: [Need a rollback/undo for tag synonym merging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73316/need-a-rollback-undo-for-tag-synonym-merging).

Comment: I found in [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work) that: *Only moderators can correct a bad synonym.* So this answers my first question - it seems that moderators can do this.

Comment: Yes on the site where I am moderator, I have on the synonyms page  a button  that seems to simply cancel, there is also one seems to change the direction. I never tried either and do not want to do so just for testing, but from the interface it seems pretty obvious this is what would happen.

Comment: I have posted basically the same question to meta.SE. It is probably a more appropriate place and perhaps it has better chance of getting an answer there. [What happens with the tagged questions when a tag-synonym is cancelled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260189/what-happens-with-the-tagged-questions-when-a-tag-synonym-is-cancelled)