# Should "natural-numbers" really be a synonym for "elementary-number-theory"?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

The title said it all. I disagree with this tag synonym. I (more than once) used "natural-numbers" to tag my questions about the logic structure of natural numbers, more related to logic and model theory than number theory. I then wondered where this strange number theory tag came from. Once, someone told me to replace this gibberish PA, ZFC, etc. because he came from the "elementary-number-theory" tag to my question, but those abbreviations are well understood in the domain of mathematical logic.

Are there actual reasons for this synonym?

Actually, I have enough reputation to vote for tag synonyms, but I do not know if this gives me the ability to  cast deletion votes. If so, could one please hint me how to do so?

Comment: Consider posting in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25694/tag-management-2017 instead of creating a new thread. That said, I agree this synonym should go (and likely the tag itself). // On the side question,  I believe once a syn was created it needs a mod to remove it.

Comment: About the question in the last paragraph - as quid said, a synonym cannot be removed by regular users. I will also add that the questions tagged with this tag during the existence of the synonym remain tagged with the master-tag even after cancelling the synonym. See also: [What happens with the tagged questions when a tag-synonym is cancelled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260189) (This is linked also in the comments here: [What happens when a tag-synonym is cancelled?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20778))